# Trying to deploy full stack app to Heroku, got wrong response data

Tags: heroku, deployment, axios

I wanna deploy full stack app on heroku, but I've got different res.data on the web when I am trying log in to my app. I should have:

`{ userName: "userName", userId: 1, token: token", isAuthorized: true, error: ""}`

but I've got:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="fontello/css/fontello.css"><title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.8a9a299b.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.e17a5aa6.js"></script></body></html>
```

server package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm start\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run-script build && cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

I'm using typeOrm and this is my connection options:

```
const options: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: "sqlite",
  logging: true,
  database: "db/mydb.db",
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [
    "build/entity/**/*.js"
  ]
};
```

This is my login request from client:

```
export const loginRequest = userData => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });
  return axios
    .create({ baseURL: `${baseUrl}` })
    .post("/api/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      dispatch(redirect("/"));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(loginError(error));
    });
};
```

baseUrl:
`"https://react-app-map-creator.herokuapp.com"`

project structure:

[image]

After POST i have status 200. I've tried many methods to solve this problem. I haven't anny erros in my console. Can someone give me some tips to fix that issue?

I edited again. My routes file has object with :

```
  {
    path: "/api/login",
    method: "post",
    action: login
  }
```

and my controller for login:

```
export async function login(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const userRepository = getManager().getRepository(User);
  const userDB = await userRepository.findOne({
    login: request.body.login
  });

  const Reject = () => {
    return response.status(401).json({
      errorMessage: "login or password is incorrect"
    });
  };
  if (userDB) {
    bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, userDB.password, (err, res) => {
      if (res) {
        const userData = {
          login: request.body.login,
          userId: userDB.id,
          isAdmin: userDB.isAdmin
        };
        jwt.sign(
          { userData },
          "secretkey",
          { expiresIn: "86400s" },
          (err, token) => {
            response.json({
              userName: userDB.login,
              userId: userDB.id,
              token: token,
              isAuthorized: true,
              error: ""
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        Reject();
      }
    });
  } else {
    Reject();
  }
}
```

PS When I use `npm run dev` on local everything works perfect.

Comment: You're returning a web page in your response, add the backend code for the endpoint `POST /api/login` to your question so we can help you.

Comment: You edited your question and added the folder structure for your project, what I asked for is the code for the `POST /api/login` endpoint. It's probably inside a file in folder `src/routes`.

Comment: Testing your app here, are you sure you don't have a route with a wildcard interfering with all other routes? For example, I can `POST https://react-app-map-creator.herokuapp.com/3252345` and I still get the login page as a response. Are the other routes working as usual?

Comment: Even if you want to redirect all requests to your login page if the user is not logged in, you shouldn't redirect `POST` requests there. Return status 401 (Unauthorized) instead in this case.

Comment: At local path of my Login component : ```http://localhost:3000/login``` and my path to login server is ```htttp://localhost:8080/api/login```. Its similar.

Comment: Maybe my authorization code do that: ```export const AuthApp = ({
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (<Route {...rest} render={props => checkAuth()
      ? (<AppComponent/>)
      : (<Redirect from="/" exact="exact" to={{
          pathname: "/login"
        }}/>)}/>);
};
```

Comment: Is your Git repository public?  I think it will be easier to help you if I see the whole code base.

Comment: ```https://github.com/one92tb/mapCreator``` I remove few commits today, because It doesn't work correctly, so code can be little different.

Comment: Tested your code here, it's weird how it works locally but doesn't work on Heroku. It probably is a configuration issue. I don't think I can help you, sorry.